# Fill materialize autocomplete component with vue variable

Tags: jquery, vue.js, autocomplete, materialize

i'm using the matarialize autocomplete component and i need to set its data with an array stored in vue.js

```
       data:{
            param:[]
       },
       mounted(){
            this.init();
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                data: {

                },
            });
        },
```

How can i pass in the jquery function the param variable stored in vue data? This array is filled with JSON data that contains strings from my database.

Comment: what does the array look like?

Comment: ["rome", "london", "new york", ....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have your array:

```
var countries = ["rome", "london", "new york"];
```

And we need to transform it into an object, so that the autocomplete can use it, like this:

```
data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
```

We do this is three steps:

1. Create an empty object

   ```
   var data = {};
   ```
2. Loop over the countries array and create a key value pair for each in the data object. Note we use 'null' as the value unless we are using images.

   ```
   for (const key of countries) {
     data[key] = null;
   }
   ```
3. Finally, set data to be equal to this new object (which I've also named data)

   ```
   var options = {
      data: data
   }
   ```

When you initialize the autocomplete, we pass the data through the options object:

```
   var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);
```

Working codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/WNQjYaK).

Full code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');

    var countries = ["rome", "london", "new york"];

    var data = {};

    for (const key of countries) {
          data[key] = null;
    }

    var options = {
      data: data
    }

    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);

  });
```

https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html